# Mysql date select by month interval given from another table

Tags: mysql, datediff, dateadd

i have in first table date and months in another table
I trying to find all expiring rows in next month
i need to show expiration date and days

This is the table with months:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `providers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `validity` enum('6','12','24') NOT NULL DEFAULT '12' COMMENT 'months',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

i try get expiring date with this query, but return not correct result:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(t1.`date`, INTERVAL p.`validity` MONTH) AS expiring 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN providers p ON p.id = t1.provider_id
```

if the date is: **2014-01-01** and validity is **12 months** result is 2014-03-01
i don't know how this is happen, the correct result must be **2015-01-01**

i try query like:

```
SELECT 
DATE_ADD(t1.`date`, INTERVAL (SELECT validity FROM providers WHERE id = t1.provider_id) MONTH) 
FROM table t1
```

This query work normally but very slow if you have big database.

The skeleton of the query need to be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AS expiring, 
  datediff(NOW(), expiring) AS days 
FROM 
  table 
WHERE 
  expiring BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(expiring, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the help page on the ENUM data type for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Here you learn that when you pull back a numeric type from your ENUM-typed field you get the INDEX of the ENUM value, not the value itself. It states

> "If you retrieve an ENUM value in a numeric context, the column
>   value's index is returned."

It also states earlier in that section:

> If you wish to use a number as an enumeration value, you must enclose it in quotation marks. If the quotation marks are omitted, the number is regarded as an index. For this and other reasons—as explained later in this section—we strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration values.

I believe you are getting the ENUM index of 2 and so your INTERVAL formula is only adding 2 months to the date. Seems like the best option here is to store that value as an INTEGER and deal with the field validation on the front end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to enclose them in quotation marks - not help, maybe its good idea to change ENUM type

Comment: I've not used ENUM before, but it seems like it might be a dead end in this case. I can't imagine how you could grab the value in a non-numeric-context AND use it in a numeric context. At the best it would probably take some nested CASTs and maybe a fakey string concatenation or something, but that doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: i change the type to tynyint(4) and now everything its correct. Thank you